# Form flicker when update control

Tags: ms-access

I use the code below to set all of the controls for different users:

```vb
DoCmd.Echo False
Me.Painting = False
Application.Echo False, "Updating"

On Error Resume Next
If Flag Then
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        ctl.enabled = True
        ctl.Locked = False
    Next
Else
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        ctl.enabled = False
        ctl.Locked = True
    Next
End If
```

Window will flicker seriously.  I tryed `DoCmd.Echo`, `Me.Painting` and `Applcaiton.Echo` to avoid flicker but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have a bunch of different pieces of code to set some pages visible or not, based on set (or not set) values, and when you tab from the main textbox on the form, that triggers some of this code, but it causes the rest of the code to cycle through the tab control, which looks horrible on the screen. I want to disable that refreshing until the code is done and then just show the results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Controls are in different tabs.  Form will jump from one tab to the other tab when settign control which cause screen flick.